# Как в Python выбрать элемент из списка со значениями float?

Tags: python, list, циклы, список, float

У меня список `param_list` со значениями типа `float`, полученными в цикле: `[0.157, 0.157, 0.157, 0.157]`. Фактически мне надо лишь первое (с индексом ноль) значение.

Как мне перестроить сам цикл, чтобы не рассчитывать все последующие значения, или же извлечь значение с индексом ноля?

Код:

```
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283, 0.9425, 1.2566, 1.5708, 1.885, 2.1991, 2.5133]
x_j = 0.157
param_list = []
for args in range(len(x_col_list)):
    poly_0 = x_j - x_col_list[0]
    param_list.append(poly_0)

print(param_list)
```

Метод `break` точно не подходит, поскольку далее цикл будет продолжаться, рассчитывая другие значения для данного списка. Строку `param_list.append(poly_0)` тоже влево не подвинешь: цикл мне далее нужен для других расчетов

Comment: вы об этом `if not args: param_list.append(poly_0)`

Comment: Так у вас args вообще не используется. Просто уберите вообще цикл, да и список вам не нужен тогда. Что-то непонятно.

Comment: Благодарю! Получил одно значение)

Comment: @CrazyElf, args используется в данном цикле далее